# Problem with not working styles in rails application on particular view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Has somebody experienced similar problem?

I have small blog app for learning purpose. I've created some views which are listed on the screenshot, also added boostrap at the beggining to the application.scss file. Everything worked perfectly until i've added the new 'Category' directory and several views to it recently. Styles don't work in any file under 'category' directory. Even a boostrap doesnt work. Tried to add categories.scss and change the h1 to red but that doesnt work neither. The strangest thing is that every other view works perfectly (styles and boostrap available). Only the Categories directory doesnt have connection to the styles.
 [image: actual view structure]

Comment: Could you show the code in your categories controller please

Comment: ok i fixed it already. Found out that Category controller inheritance was wrong. Not from ApplicationController but the ActiveController